# How can I use one parameter file for templates that use some different parameters? (Azure LogicApp deployment using Powershell in DevOps Pipelines)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-logic-apps, azure-powershell

So I am working on a project right now and I am facing an issue. In the company I work at we use two different resource groups, one for demo and then for productive. Before now we used to manually copy every new Logic App from the demo account and change the parameters so that it uses the correct ones for productive. We have around 80 logic apps as of now, and we seperate them in groups. The objective is to make it much easier and with as little as possible manual work required.

We are using them to sync SQL tables, CRM data and a lot of other stuff together. So I have many logic apps that use different parameters. For example, one can sync from the Calender to the SQL server, and the other one syncing two SQL tables but each table has to be accessed with a different user. What I want to do is have 6-7 parameter files depending on the sync. But when the deployment sees that I have parameter values that arent being used by a template, the deployment fails with the following error that makes it necessary to create a new parameter file for almost all new logic apps:

`Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The template parameters 'sql_server......' in the parameters file are not valid; they are not present in the original template and can therefore not be provided at deployment time. The only supported parameters for this template are 'logicAppName, logicAppLocation........ sql-8_username, sql-8_password, sql-8_sqlConnectionString'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy/#parameter-file for usage details.'.`

Is there a way to make these parameters optional so that each templates uses the ones it needs? I googled around but the main thing I found did not help much => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-best-practices#parameters

Thanks a lot for any help you guys can provide!

Answer (score -1):

You can make it optional to provide a value for a param by using a `defaultValue`.

- Any `defaultValue` supplied for a parameter must be valid for all users in the default deployment configuration.
- Do not provide default values for user names, passwords (or anything that requires a secureString) or anything that will increase the attack surface area of the application
- Do not use empty strings as default values (use language expressions to facilitate the scenario)
- Template expressions can be used to create default values

Reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/1-CONTRIBUTION-GUIDE/best-practices.md#parameters

Comment: The problem is that as soon as the script sees that I have a parameter name the template does not use, it throws me an error and the deployment does not happen. Its not about the parameter values, its about the parameter existing in the file. Or I did something wrong.